# How to Calculate the Power Absorbed by Resistor 2

Tags: power, resistors

[image]I'm sure I am doing something wrong as I keep getting the wrong answer, but if someone could explain how to solve this question for me that would be great.

Comment: Show us your work.

Comment: working out P=I^2*R
P=(-0.0322)^2*47
P=0.049W (3 s.f)

Comment: Looks good P = 0.04873148W ≈ 0.049W. Who said that this is a wrong answer?

Comment: The power isn't absorbed, but dessipated.
And I don't see any wrong work here, as current flows through both resistors the same, while the resistance is different. My result is the same, P = 0.04783W

Comment: The worksheet answers said it was wrong but I'll assume it's an error as you said it was correct. Thanks G36 and Jakey!

Comment: What did the worksheet say?

Comment: I find the opposing polarities of V1 and V2 interesting; either this schematic is an incomplete snippet, or there is more wrong in the worksheet than a simple computation.

Comment: worksheet can go to dustbin

Comment: Is this about negative resistance?

Answer (score -1):

Convention is that positive current flows from plus to minus (higher to lower voltage.) Adjacent R's with opposite signed voltage drops suggests the diagram has an error. Either another branch should connect to the node between them, or some similarly crucial piece of information has been omitted.

Comment: The order and directions are stupid but that's common in first year electronics - they want you to think hard about relative voltages and current flowing in different directions. The question makes sense if for example V1 is negative and V2 is positive (note that even the current is negative, flowing the opposite way in relation to the arrow)